# NodeJs и PHP sites on one VPS

Tags: php, node.js, apache, nginx, vps

I have two sites work on Yii framework, and one sites work on Node.js use port 3030. I want use 80 port for Node.js. How to do it? all three sites work...

My config file in node.js

```
{
  "port": 3030,
  "mongoose": {
    "uri": "mongodb://localhost/side"
  },
  "session" : {
    "secret": "KillJoneDou",
    "key": "sid",
    "resave": true,
    "saveUninitialized": true,
    "cookie": {
      "maxAge": null,
      "path": "/",
      "httpOnly": true
    }
  }
}
```

I can not just put port 80.

Comment: revers proxy listening on 80, node and php  listening other (different) ports. Proxy directs requests to the correct server: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Just to further @Steve's comment; you can run multiple applications (processes) on the same server, and you could use Nginx as a reverse proxy on your VPS to direct requests to specific ports. Nginx is recommended for NodeJS applications.

Comment: You need root access to use port 80.

Comment: On my server installed Nginx how to properly set up?